# Need help testing a REST controller that requires oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am following this example for how to test my REST controller with oauth2. [Testing an OAuth Secured API with Spring MVC](http://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc)

The code that I am stuck on is this line **`.with(httpBasic("fooClientIdPassword","secret"))`**
Does anyone know where is httpBasic method coming from? How is it instantiated, etc.? Thank you.

```
private String obtainAccessToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.add("grant_type", "password");
    params.add("client_id", "fooClientIdPassword");
    params.add("username", username);
    params.add("password", password);

    ResultActions result 
      = mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
               .params(params)
               .with(httpBasic("fooClientIdPassword","secret"))
               .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

    String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
    return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The httpBasic method comes from [SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/request/SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.html)

I suppose you cannot find it cause you have not imported the dependency in your project. Once you add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

in your pom you will be able to import and use it.